# How to reduce white space around boxes in a boxplot created using ggplot and facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, facet-wrap, graphing

I'm trying to create a boxplot representing the biomass of different plant groups according to a factor with two levels (grazed and ungrazed). I've used facet_wrap to display each group of plants separately below one another. [boxplot with lots of white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRDsL.png) But in this image, I would like to reduce the white space to the left and the right of the boxes. And maybe also the distance between the two boxes. Is there any way to do this ?

This is the code I've used to create the graph:

```
gg_bio2 <-ggplot(tf2, aes(x=Paturage, y = log(Biomasse+1), fill = Paturage)) +
  geom_boxplot(width = 0.25)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = col) +
  labs(x= "Condition de gestion", y="log(Biomasse+1) (g)") +
  facet_wrap(vars(Type.fonctionnel), drop = T, nrow = 8)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(),
        legend.position="none", 
        strip.background = element_rect(colour="black",
                                        fill="white"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = unit(c(5, 0, 0, 0), "mm")),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = unit(c(0, 5, 0, 0), "mm")),
        text = element_text(size = 22))
```

Thank you in advance!

I've tried changing the axis ratio, but that left the whole graph too narrow and unreadable. Other than that i can't find any solutions online that have this problem, it's always about the white space around the graph but not within the graph space

Comment: If your plot has a fixed overall size (I.e. you don't want to make it narrower), then _something_ needs to take up the physical space. The only things that take up horizontal space on your plot are the boxes and the white space. Your options are to change the dimensions of your plot, arrange the plots differently (perhaps two columns?), make the boxes themselves wider, increase the white space outside the plot, or accept the current white space. You can't keep the page _and_ boxes the same size but reduce white space (that doesn't make any sense logically)

Comment: Without having your data I would guess that your variable `Paturage` is a `factor`. This could creat spaces.

Comment: Does removing `width = 0.25` give you what you want?